# Issues with Expand All Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not the best at Javascript yet. I can't figure out why this expand/expand all script isn't working anymore. It was working previously and after a month of not looking at it something happened and it no longer works. It's a page that contains a list of myths and facts that can be expanded to read an answer and collapsed after reading with an expand all button at the top for easy use.

Here is the Code:

```js
expand: function() {
  $('.expand').find('p').hide();

  $('.expandall').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('closed')) {
      $(this).removeClass('closed');
      $('.expand').each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('expanded');
        $(this).find('p').slideDown();
      });
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('closed');
      $('.expand').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('expanded');
        $(this).find('p').slideUp();
      });
    }
  });
  $('.expand').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
      $(this).removeClass('expanded');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('expanded');
    }

    $(this).find('p').slideToggle();
  });
}
};
```

```css
.main .content {
  width: 68%;
  float: right;
  margin: 12px 0 0 0;
}

.main .content h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.information {}

.information .expand {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.information .expand h4 {
  color: #dd995a;
  background: url(images/expandocons.png) top left no-repeat;
  padding: 0 0 10px 45px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  min-height: 38px;
}

.information .expanded h4 {
  color: #a6848d;
  background-position: left -104px;
}

.information .expand p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.information .expand.expanded p {
  background: #f6f0ea;
}

.information #commit {
  background: url(images/commit.png) center no-repeat;
  width: 216px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.expandall {
  margin: 2em 0;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  background: #b2959d;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section main">

  <div class="content">

    <div class="information">
      <h2>Myths and Facts about Becoming a Foster Family</h2>
      <br> Foster parenting is both a challenge and a privilege. It requires dedication, patience, and lots of love. Here are some common myths and facts about being a foster parent in South Dakota.
      <br>
      <p class="expandall closed">Expand/Hide All</p>

      <div class="expand">
        <h4>Myth: Foster parents must be married and must also have children.</h4>
        <p style="display: none;">Fact: Foster parents do not need to be married or have children.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="expand">
        <h4>Myth: Older people cannot be foster parents.</h4>
        <p style="display: none;">Fact: Foster parents must be at least 21 years old. There are no other age requirements.</p>

      </div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need all that code. You can simply toggle between showing/not showing the paragraph elements:

```js
$('.expand').on('click', function() {

  // toggle only the paragraphs in the context of `.expand`
  $('p', this).toggle('show');
});

$('.all').on('click', function () {
  $('p').toggle('show');
});
```

```css
.expand p {
  display: none;
}

.sbow {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <button class="all">Expand/Hide All</button>
  <div class="expand">
    <h4>Myth: Foster parents must be married and must also have children.</h4>
    <p>Fact: Foster parents do not need to be married or have children.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="expand">
    <h4>Myth: Older people cannot be foster parents.</h4>
    <p style="display: none;">Fact: Foster parents must be at least 21 years old. There are no other age requirements.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried copying your code into a test page and using it. It still doesn't work unless it's on stack overflow? I've changed nothing in it but it still won't work?

Comment: Make sure your jQuery is wrapped in a `$(function () { ... });`. It'll ensure the DOM has loaded first before processing it.